# Set membership and inclusion confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've recently started studying discrete mathematics for my computer science degree, and I have a doubt regarding membership and inclusion. I'll explain with an example.

---

Consider the set: $ A = \{1, 2,3,4,5 \} $

*True or false?*

1. $1 \in A$
2. $\{1\} \in A$
3. $1 \subset A$
4. $\{1\} \subset A$

Number one is obviously **true**, because the element $1$ is a member of $A$.

Number two, as far as I understand, *should be* **false** because it makes no sense. Membership is between a set and an element, not between two sets. *Correct?*

Number three: I'm not sure what the answer is. Can the concept of inclusion be applied between an element and a set or only between sets?

Number four is obviously **true**, because the singleton set $\{1\}$ is a subset of $A$.

---

- Are my answers correct?
- Can the concept of membership be applied between two sets? Or is it only **always** between an element and a set?
- Can the concept of inclusion be applied between an element and a set? Or is it only **always** between two sets?
- Consider $B = \{1, 2, 3\}, C = \{\{1\}, 2, 3\}$.

  - Is $B=C$ true? (Can a singleton set be considered as an element?)
  - Is $1 \in C$ true?
  - Is $\{1\} \in C$ true?
  - Is $1 \subset C$ true?
  - Is $\{1\} \subset C$ true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that 1 and 4 are true.

On the other hand, if we're doing Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, then the truthvalues of 2 and 3 cannot be determined from the information given. For example, 2 says that $\{1\} \in A$, or in other words that $\{1\} = 1$ or $\{1\} = 2$ or $\{1\} = 3$ or $\{1\} = 4$ or $\{1\} = 5$. Are any of those statements true? Well they could be. In Zermelo's approach to defining the natural numbers, $\{1\} = 2$ is *true*, indeed this is the definition of $2$. However, in von Neumann's approach, the set $\{1\}$ is not a natural number and thus not an element of $A$.

Similarly, the truthvalue of 3 cannot be determined. It all comes down to how you define the notion "natural number."

On the other hand, other approaches to the foundations would deem 2 and 3 "ill-formed" and therefore nonsensical. They're not even false; they're just nonsense.

To answer your questions: Membership *can* be a relation between two sets (at least in ZFC). For example, $\mathbb{R} \in \{\mathbb{R}\}$ is true. Furthermore, there is no distinction between "elements" and "sets" in ZFC; everything is a set, and "element" is a relationship: we can say the set $\mathbb{R}$ is an element of $\{\mathbb{R}\}$, but there's no point in saying that something "is" an element, period.

This was quite a rushed answer because I need to get back to my assignments, so please comment with any questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I understand, basically, infinitely nesting an element into a set is equal to the element itself, correct? $\{\{\{...\{1\}...\}\}\} = 1$

---

Also, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how $\{1\} = 2$. Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: @user18921 IIRC $0:=\emptyset$ and the successor of a natural number $S(n+1):n\cup\{n\}$, so $1=\emptyset\cup\{\emptyset\}=\{\emptyset\}$ and $2=1\cup\{1\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\neq\{1\}$.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, in early mathematics, no real distinction was made between a set $X$ and the set $\{X\},$ and no real distinction was made between $\in$ and $\subset$. There came a point when they realized that there's an important distinction. Suppose $X = \{1,2,3\}.$ How many elements does $X$ have? How many elements does $\{X\}$ have? Thus $X \neq \{X\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Sets can be members of other sets. Element is just a term for a member of a set, it is not synonymous with "not a set". For example, given a set $A$, the power set of $A$ denoted by $\mathcal P(A)$ is a set whose elements are sets.

Numbers themselves *can* be represented as sets, and in modern set theory they are, and in fact **everything** is a set in the context of modern set theory. However if you are doing naive set theory then it is possible that you are assuming that numbers (say up to $\Bbb R$ or so) are not actually sets, but rather some atomic entity.

If this is indeed the case, then writing $1\subseteq A$ is indeed meaningless, because $1$ is not a set; however in the former case it is meaningful as you interpret $1$ as a particular set (e.g. $\{\varnothing\}$ is a common way, as $\varnothing$ is often represents $0$). If indeed $1$ is a set in your context, you need to know what is that set and then you can decide whether or not $1\subseteq A$ is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it mechanically.  If you remove $\{$ and $\}$ of $A$ you'll see a comma-separated list 
$$1,2,3,4,5$$
of the elements of $A$. So clearly (1) is true, since “1” is in that list and (2) is false since “$\{1\}$” does not appear in that list.

For $C$ the list of its element is
$$\{1\},2,3$$
hence $\{1\}$ is an element of $C$.

Mechanically you'll get a subset by removing first the braces, then choose some elements from the element-list and put braces round those elements again.  So (3) is false and (4) is right.

Obexample: for $M=\{\{0\},0\}$ it's true that $0\in M$, $\{0\}\in M$, $\{0\}\subset M$ and $\{\{0\}\}\subset M$  Do you see why?

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to say that (2) is false since "$\{1\}$" does not appear in the list.  Although that particular _notation_ does not appear there, one still has to check whether "$\{1\}$" is _equal_ to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 as user18921 pointed out.

Comment: So in which case is $\{a\}=a$?

Comment: That is never the case, by the axiom of regularity.  I meant that you should check that $\{a\} \ne b$ for *every* $b$ in the list.  For example, if $A = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ then technically speaking we have $\{0\} \in A$ because $\{0\} = 1$, although this would probably only be used in a set theory class and not in OP's discrete math class.  More generally, my point is that it's not quite enough to check whether a given *notation* appears in the list, because the same object might be denoted in different ways.  (I'm not sure why I made such a nitpicky comment, or who user18921 is.)

Answer (score 0):

Some  simple examples to clarify the distinction between membership and inclusion.

Suppose that Peter  belongs to a football club, let's call this club  the "Lions".  Let's admit that a club can be defined as a set of persons.

Peter **belongs / is a member** of the set "Lions".

In that club, there are 3 teams, Team A, Team B, Team C.

Neither Team A, nor Team B nor Team C is a member of the set Lions: **all the members of the club are persons, but a team is not a person, it is a set of persons.**

True, Team A is a member of some set, namely, the set of the Lions's Teams. **Team A belongs to the set T = { Team A, Team B, Team C}.** Although there are 11 players in each team, the set T has only 3 elements.

The correct relation between each Team, say Team A, and the set Lions is the **inclusion** relation. Team A is not a member of the set Lions, it is a **subset** of the set Lions, it is included in that set.

True, all the elements of team A are alson elements of the set Lions ( this is the definition of " inclusion") but the set **Team A is not itself an element of the set Lions.**

Suppose the club Lions belongs to a football league. The football league is a set of cluds. The League is a set whose elements are clubs, not of persons, nor of teams.

**Peter belongs to the set Lions, the set Lions belongs to the set League, but Peter does not belong to the set League**: the set "League" is a set of clubs, not a set of persons.

**Thus, the membership relation is not transitive!**

One cannot say : a belongs to the set X, the set X is an element of  Z, therefore necessarily a belongs to Z.

**The inclusion relation is transitive.**

Suppose the set { Peter; John, David} is a subset of Team A. Since Team A is, in turn, a subset of the set " Lions", it follows that the set { Peter, John, David} is ( by transitivity) a subset of the set Lions.

Of which set is the set Lions a subset? Not of the set League. That would mean ( according the definition of inclusion) that all the elements of Lions are also elements of League; in other words , that all the members of Lions are football clubs ( since League is a set of Clubs)!  No ... The set Lions is a subset of the **union** of all the clubs ( that is the set of all persons that belong to one football club or another). Let's call this set P ( for players, all football players in the country, at least all those that belong to a football club). All the members of the set Lions are also members of the set P ( they are all players, football players): **so the set Lions is included in P.**

Remak.- **Saying that the membership relation is not transitive does not mean that it is intransitive**. There are ( so to say) special cases in which an element of an element of S is also an element of S.

Example. 
 The number 0 = { } is an element of the number 1 = {0} . The number 1 is an element of the number 2={0,1}. And the number 0 is also an element of the number 2.