# Does the Member $\in$ property also check whether the given value exists in a subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Quick question. Does $7 \in \{1, \{4, 7\}\}$ return True because it still exists in the subset? If so then can you please give a source as well that explains it all.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how "return" is being used here, but the claim that $7 \in \{1,\{4,7\}\}$ is clearly false.

Comment: Also, I'm confused by the tag "multisets".  Nothing in the Question relates to a multiset.

Comment: **NO** : the members of $\{ 1, \{ 4,7 \} \}$ are $1$ and $\{ 4,7 \}$.

Comment: The [*membership* relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation) : $\in$ is a *binary* relation (like e.g. $<(n,m)$, usually written: $n < m$); trivially, we have that $\in (x, A)$ **iff** $x \in A$.

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518839/set-membership-and-inclusion-confusion/518885#518885 will be helpful.

Comment: Conclusion : "the **membership** relation $x \in A$ returns TRUE only when  the given element $x$ belongs to the set $A$".

Comment: That makes sense thanks guys! I wasn't sure whether the Member property checked on just 1 level or all but that makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

No. The $∈$ operator strictly means elements within a set. In this case, the elements of the set are 1 and {4, 7}, and not just 7.